# How do I get three tikcd diagrams to be colinear minipages?

Tags: positioning, minipage, tikz-cd

So yeah, like my question says I am having trouble with these minipages. For 2 diagrams
it usually does not complain too much. At the end of each minipage I get overfull hboxes,
for what it's worth.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{quiver}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document} 

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            &  & \bullet\text{ }a \\
            b \text{ } \bullet \arrow[rru, "f", bend left] &  &  \\
            & c \text{ } \bullet \arrow[lu, "g", bend left] \arrow[ruu, "h"', bend right] & 
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{minipage}{\caption*{$\mbf{G}$}}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.21\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            &  & \bullet\text{ }a \\
            b \text{ } \bullet \arrow[rru, "f", bend left] &  &   \\
            & c \text{ } \bullet \arrow[lu, "g", bend left] \arrow[ruu, "h"', bend right] &                   
        \end{tikzcd}
    \end{minipage}{\caption*{$\mbf{G}'$}}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            & & \bullet \text{ } a \\
            b \text{ } \bullet \arrow[rru, "f", bend left] &  & \\
            & c \text{ } \bullet \arrow[lu, "g", bend left] \arrow[ruu, "h"', bend right] & 
        \end{tikzcd} 
    \end{minipage}{\caption*{$\mbf{G}''$}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the width of the minipages is too short. I believe a `tabular` is better.

The diagrams fit on a line if you reduce their size. A `\[...\]` is better, plus a trick to space them as much as possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\mbf}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document} 

\[
\hspace{1em}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
    &  & \bullet\ a \\
    b \ \bullet \arrow[rru, "f", bend left] &  &  \\
    & c \text{ } \bullet \arrow[lu, "g", bend left] \arrow[ruu, "h"', bend right] & 
  \end{tikzcd}
\\
\mbf{G}
\end{array}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
    &  & \bullet\ a \\
    b \ \bullet \arrow[rru, "f", bend left] &  &   \\
    & c \ \bullet \arrow[lu, "g", bend left] \arrow[ruu, "h"', bend right] &                   
  \end{tikzcd}
\\
\mbf{G}'
\end{array}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep=small]
    & & \bullet\ a \\
    b \ \bullet \arrow[rru, "f", bend left] &  & \\
    & c \ \bullet \arrow[lu, "g", bend left] \arrow[ruu, "h"', bend right] & 
  \end{tikzcd} 
\\
\mbf{G}''
\end{array}
\hspace{1em}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Backslash-space is simpler than `\text{ }`.

Please, ensure that the example you show can be compiled straight away. Yours didn't because `tikz-cd` was missing and `quiver` is nonstandard (I see no trace of it on CTAN).

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant they should be colinear horizontally, not vertically. And yes, quiver is nonstandard; there is an extra sty file that goes along with it. Perhaps I should include that somehow...

Comment: @LatexEnjoyer I reworked the answer based on your comment.

Comment: Looks perfect! Thanks for thinking of my question and for your advice